Specific keys press not working (CTRL+SHIFT+E)
I'm creating a system to detect some key press but CTRL+SHIFT+E is not working to me. Here is my code:


function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.key === 'E') {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Key press!');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);



If I change E key to T key, for example, it will work!
There are no errors. How can I solve this? I'm using Google Chrome and I'm not sure if this is happening in other browsers.
Thank you

Can't reproduce. Are you sure you don't have this same shortcut at, say, OS level?

No! It was working until last month. I did not change the code. In my other notebook it doesn't work either, just with these keys. Was it any Chrome update, maybe?

Likely some Chrome extension interference. You can go incognito mode to test, which automatically turns off all extensions (unless you explicitly configure otherwise)

Not working for me, even using incognito mode
